Checkupkeep function is not showing to get called by automation nodes for Chainlink Keepers

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xc3062430Aa70dABd1e33a702323aB6c4980883fd#code
Question:
The argument for performupkeep(input) is coming from my checkupkeep. So what should I give as input during register?
(Afaik checkupkeep is the function that is called off-chain and if the condition satisfies it calls performupkeep and the on-chain activity starts.)

I think you’re slightly misunderstanding this. As far as I can get from your attached screenshot, you’re creating a Time-based Upkeep, in which it’s asking you to select a target function that you want to be executed on the basis of a certain schedule (as specified by the cron expression).
So, in case of Time-based Upkeep, you don’t really need the checkUpkeep() and performUpkeep() functions, as the Automation node keep checking the scheduler off-chain and trigger the targeted function accordingly.
And, in case of implementing the Log and Custom Logic Upkeeps, your contract must meet the requirements to be compatible with the AutomationCompatibleInterface contract. And thus, you need to override the checkUpkeep() and performUpkeep() functions, and performUpkeep() function is supposed to be triggered by the Automation Node.
As far as their inputs are concerned, they take inputs of type bytes named as checkData in case of checkUpkeep() and performData in case of performUpkeep(). So, you can enter the initial checkData argument while entering upkeep details at the time of registration or leave it empty (i.e., 0x) depending on your use-case. And, similarly you can utilize performData by passing the appropriate inputs within the performData based on the results from your checkUpkeep(). You can refer this example for better understanding.

thanks for the reply! one follow up question here. I've a function  function "returnRentedproperty(uint nftId) internal" which changes state of  map , so why it is not showing in the list.  you can refer the contract here : https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xc3062430Aa70dABd1e33a702323aB6c4980883fd#code

Because it’s internal function, only external and public functions are listed. You need to make it public if you want that to be shown in the list, and you can’t make it external because you are accessing it internally in the performUpkeep() function as well.

For custom logic automation how frequent does automation nodes call checkupkeep() to understand the need to call performupkeep()?

It’s checked every second. And, depending on the returned value of the upkeepNeeded boolean, if it’s true then the performUpkeep() is called.
